# Discovering Bluetooth devices in Python with M1 MacBook

Tags: python, bluetooth, apple-m1, pybluez

Is there any way to discover nearby Bluetooth devices using Python on macOS running on the newer Apple Silicon?

I tried `Pybluez`, but `lightblue`, one of its dependencies, doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: Have you tried using Bleak? https://pypi.org/project/bleak/

Comment: Yes! Discovered it yesterday by chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bleak, it works for me on M1 macOS Ventura

Just make sure you have the necessary permissions to access Bluetooth from your terminal app (iTerm, for example), I spent really annoying 15 minutes on this error. go to "System Preferences" > "Privacy & Security" > "Bluetooth" and enable access for your terminal application.

Install bleak using pip:

```bash
pip install bleak
```

Here's a short example that demonstrates how to discover nearby Bluetooth devices:

```py
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakScanner

async def discover_devices():
    devices = await BleakScanner.discover()
    for device in devices:
        print(f"Device: {device.name}, Address: {device.address}")

asyncio.run(discover_devices())
```

Learn more at [Bleak official documentation](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Happy Bluetoothing!